# friendly_id: Renew slugs optionally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, parameters, slug, friendly-id

I want to allow users to
*renew*
the slug of an entry by clicking a checkbox.

I know the function
**should_generate_new_friendly_id?**
, but not how to use it in this case since it is defined in the model and cannot read params attributes.

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 2):

On the model, you can add an attr_accessor to test for this case

```
attr_accessor :should_generate_new_friendly_id

before_save :generate_new_friendly_id, :if => :should_generate_new_friendly_id

def generate_new_friendly_id
  self.friendly_id = ...
end
```

Then, in the form, you can provide a checkbox with the name 'should_generate_new_friendly_id'.  It should all work as you expect...